# Wait for method to be finished C#

Tags: c#

I'm communication with an external device (PLC) and he requests data.

I have an event that checks when a value changes in my PLC (for example `"NeedNewPosition"` or `"NeedNewBarValues"`)

I would like to change my code that it will handle them one by one. Sometimes it seems he's handling 2 of them at the same time. (probably since one takes longer than the other to finish)
I've read something about async methods and wait/tasks etc, but that seems a lot of work for something this simple.

The code:

```cs
private void PLCValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool xDisplayValue = false;
    PLCVar plcvariable = (PLCVar)sender;
    string VarName = plcvariable.DisplayName;

    switch (VarName)
    {
        case "NEEDNEWPOSITION": //Writing required position to PLC
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(plcvariable.Value))
        {
            SearchNewPosition();
            OPCclient.SendVarToPLC(OPCclient.SendPlcAllBarsFinished, "FALSE");
            OPCclient.SendVarToPLC(OPCclient.SendPLCAllMagnetsFinished, "FALSE");

            MagnetsInArea = GetMagnetsInWorkArea();
            SymbolsInArea = GetSymbolsInWorkArea();
            BarsInArea = GetBarsInWorkArea();
        }
        else
        {
            OPCclient.SendVarToPLC(OPCclient.SendPLCNewPositionIsSend, "FALSE");
        }
        break;

        case "NEEDNEWBARVALUES": //Writing Bar Values to PLC
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(plcvariable.Value))
        {
            OPCclient.SendVarToPLC(OPCclient.SendPLCBarStrippedOK, "FALSE");
            OPCclient.SendVarToPLC(OPCclient.SendPLCBarMagnetsOK, "FALSE");
            OPCclient.SendVarToPLC(OPCclient.SendPLCAllBarMagnetsLoose, "FALSE");

            SetFirstBarValues();

            OffsetsCalculated = false;

            StartVisualisation?.Invoke(this, null); //%M59
        }
        else //if (!Convert.ToBoolean(plcvariable.Value))
        {
            OPCclient.SendVarToPLC(OPCclient.SendPLCBarDataIsSend, "FALSE");
        }
        break;
```

Comment: If you post code, could you please post a complete compilable block and format it properly? Thanks.

Comment: So I guess the `PLCValueChanged` is being fired by something else and you want one event to finish before another one tries to call it again?

Comment: To your question: Yes, Events _can_ fire in that manner that one fires while the previous one is still being processed. If this occurs, you need to consider two things: 1. Is it happening constantly? That means if _every_ fired event will overlap with its predecessor, then you will encounter a pile-up, no matter what you do. If you only have peeks, then building a pipeline is probably what you want. 2. You do not want to have the processing of the event on the Event-Thread if the processing takes long. SO you may want to build some sort of pipeline, anyway. async _will not help for 1.)_

Comment: @DavidG correct, I because the `NeedNewPosition` receives `BarsInArea` and he needs that information at the `NeedNewBarValues`. Thats why I want the second call  to wait for the first one to be finished.

Comment: @Fildor - That would only happen if multiple threads are being used. In a single threaded model you can't get overlapping threads.

Comment: This question is actually too broad for Stack Overflow. That's because there is no general answer. It always depends on the situation (hardware, platform, OS, etc) and business requirements. I can give you the way we do it (user app for usb measuring device), but that might not work for you. It all depends. **AND** there are also multiple possible solutions.

Comment: @Enigmativity That's correct. I wrote it _can_ happen. Sounds like it does, no?

Comment: Also: _"I've read something about async methods and wait/tasks etc, but that seems a lot of work for something this simple."_ that's a great misconception. Unless you want your CPU to waste cycles doing nothing while waiting for an external device to respond, tasks are exactly what you need. They've become a core functionality of C#, so you should really pick up on them. And they're actually quite simple to use (Threads were difficult, Tasks easy).

Comment: @JHBonarius Not really in this case. If OP's (only) problem was waiting for I/O - sure. But this seems to be more complex. It's also unclear whether OP's OPC Lib allows for async I/O to start with.

Comment: @Fildor ah that might be an issue. Still you could make a polling mechanism, which uses `await Task.Delay()` instead of a waiting loop. If that's a thing in his app.

Comment: @JHBonarius The thing is: I (/We) have no idea how the event source works. It may be multithreaded or it may not. Depending on that we are in completely different ballparks to start with. Then we don't know if it's happening just in a fraction of events or always. Again- if "always" then the handling is not fast enough regardless what we do. Etc ...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for a [Semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)). Like the like/wiki says:

> a semaphore is a variable or abstract data type used to control access to a common resource by multiple threads and avoid critical section problems in a concurrent system such as a multitasking operating system.

I.e. you can use the semaphore to "block" until a resource becomes available again.

You have multiple types of semaphores in C#, but the simplest to use is the [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim).

You can just define a static one for your singleton class instance

```cs
private static readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new(1, 1);
```

The `1,1` means: "1 is available, and there can only be 1".

Then in your code:

```cs
// take a semaphore, or wait until it is available
await _semaphore.WaitAsync(Timeout.Infinite, cancellationToken);
try
{
    [.. your work...]
}
finally
{
    // give the semaphore back
    _semaphore.Release();
}
```

Note, I'm using `await` here, because this means the thread becomes available for other tasks. It will also wait indefinitely until a semaphore is available. The way to stop this is the `cancallationToken`.

Comment: I believe a `new Semaphore(1, 1)` is basically the same as a [`ManualResetEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualresetevent?view=net-6.0).

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride I don't think so. That looks like old blocking Threading stuff. Nothing `async` that you can `await`.

Comment: They're all based on `WaitHandle`, `ManualResetEvent` is just missing an async interface (which might not be helpful in this context, since OPs method would then return `async void` anyway. My point merely is: if you're creating a `new Semaphore(1, 1)` then dotnet's zoo of types for thread locking offers other solutions implementing this special case.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride I don't agree, you don't want to block the thread for several reasons imho. If additional logic is required to make an alternative like the `ManualResetEvent` async, I don't see the added value. By the way a `Semaphore` is something different then a `SemaphoreSlim`. It seems you are confusing the two.

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware of that difference. Thanks for the hint. So a `Semaphore` works with multiple competing processes and a `SemaphoreSlim` only works for multiple competing threads from the same process, right?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Yes, basically that. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/semaphore-and-semaphoreslim). A semaphore is much heavier than the slim variant.

Answer (score 0):

You could wait for the processing of the first event to be finished using an [`AutoResetEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.autoresetevent?view=net-6.0):

```cs
using System.Threading;
// ...

// declare lock as a static class member
private static AutoResetEvent barsInAreaLoaded = new AutoResetEvent(false);

private void PLCValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...

    switch (VarName)
    {
        case "NEEDNEWPOSITION":
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(plcvariable.Value))
        {
            // ...
            BarsInArea = GetBarsInWorkArea();
            // signal waiting thread that bars are ready
            barsInAreaLoaded.Set();
        }
        // ...
        break;

        case "NEEDNEWBARVALUES":
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(plcvariable.Value))
        {
            // ...
            
            // block until bars are ready
            barsInAreaLoaded.WaitOne();
            SetFirstBarValues();
            
            // ...
        }
        // ...
        break;
```

Note that this will only work if you are sure that the processing of two corresponding `NEEDNEWPOSITION` and `NEEDNEWBARVALUES` messages overlap. If some of those messages actually pile up this won't solve your problem and you should consider implementing some kind of message queue/pipeline.

Comment: Keep in mind: Event Handlers are supposed to execute _quickly_.

Comment: @Fildor I assume this best practice exists to avoid multi-threading issues like race conditions which is exactly the problem OP is facing. So yeah, the right answer should be "implement a message queue".